# Can't change the SVG color before placing it inside a canvas element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, svg, html5-canvas

I have an SVG that looks like this (I can't alter the SVG code):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg id="shape" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
    <path d="M29.57,19.75l-3.5-13.59c-.12-.52-.45-.97-.89-1.23-2.03-1.25-4.19-1.28-6.22-.08-.59,.35-.96,1-.96,1.71v3.45h-4v-3.45c0-.71-.37-1.36-.96-1.71-2.04-1.19-4.19-1.16-6.22,.08-.44,.27-.76,.72-.88,1.22l-3.51,13.61h0c-.28,.7-.44,1.45-.44,2.25,0,3.31,2.69,6,6,6s6-2.69,6-6v-2h4v2c0,3.31,2.69,6,6,6s6-2.69,6-6c0-.79-.16-1.55-.44-2.25h0Zm-5.44-13.11l2.58,10.01c-.81-.41-1.73-.65-2.7-.65-1.54,0-2.94,.59-4.01,1.55l-.02-10.98c1.42-.83,2.74-.81,4.16,.08Zm-16.26-.01c1.42-.87,2.75-.89,4.14-.08v10.99c-1.06-.95-2.46-1.54-4-1.54-.98,0-1.89,.24-2.71,.65L7.86,6.63Zm.14,19.37c-2.21,0-4-1.79-4-4s1.79-4,4-4,4,1.79,4,4-1.79,4-4,4Zm6-8v-6h4v6h-4Zm10,8c-2.21,0-4-1.79-4-4s1.79-4,4-4,4,1.79,4,4-1.79,4-4,4Z"/>
</svg>
```

I need to place this SVG in a canvas element that has a square background color, with this SVG being placed in the middle. However, the SVG is black, and I need to make it white before placing it inside the canvas. This is my current code:

```
export const useRenderIcon = (
    previewCanvas: React.RefObject<HTMLCanvasElement>,
    selectedColor: Color,
    selectedSVG: Svg
): void => {
    useEffect(() => {
        if (previewCanvas.current) {
            const ctx = previewCanvas.current.getContext("2d");

            if (ctx) {
                previewCanvas.current.style.width = `${PREVIEW_CANVAS_SIZE}px`;
                previewCanvas.current.style.height = `${PREVIEW_CANVAS_SIZE}px`;

                // draw icon background color
                ctx.fillStyle = selectedColor.color;
                ctx.fillRect(0, 0, previewCanvas.current.width, previewCanvas.current.height);

                // draw icon svg
                const offset = previewCanvas.current.width - PREVIEW_SVG_SIZE; // calculate offset to center icon to middle of canvas

                const svgIconImage = new Image();
                svgIconImage.setAttribute("src", selectedSVG.uri);
                svgIconImage.setAttribute("width", `${PREVIEW_SVG_SIZE}`);
                // trying to make it white
                svgIconImage.style.fill = "white";
                svgIconImage.style.stroke = "white";
                svgIconImage.onload = () => {
                    // trying to make it white
                    svgIconImage.style.fill = "white";
                    svgIconImage.style.stroke = "white";
                    ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
                    ctx.drawImage(svgIconImage, offset / 2, offset / 2, PREVIEW_SVG_SIZE, PREVIEW_SVG_SIZE);
                };
            }
        }
    }, [previewCanvas, selectedColor, selectedSVG]);
};
```

But the lines `svgIconImage.style.fill = "white";` and `svgIconImage.style.stroke = "white";` don't make any difference. The icon does show up on the canvas with the correct background color, but the SVG icon remains black instead of turning white. How can I fix this?

Comment: You can not manipulate elements inside an SVG that was embedded via an Image element, from the outside. Outside CSS can only work, if the SVG was embedded directly in the HTML document - but since you are trying to paint it onto a canvas here, that's not an option either.

Comment: The only option I see here, is that you use AJAX to fetch the actual SVG code from `selectedSVG.uri`, then manipulate that SVG _code_ by inserting `fill` and `stroke` attributes, and finally create a Data URI from it, that you can then again use as an image source.

Comment: Ended up fetching the .svg file, using a DOMParser to parse the SVG string, used setAttribute to add the fill attribute and reverted it back to string. Then added it as a DataURL to the src attribute of the Image object and it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up fetching the .svg file, using a DOMParser to parse the SVG string, used setAttribute function to add the fill attribute, and reverted the parsed SVG back to a string. Then added it as a DataURL to the src attribute of the Image object.

```
export const useRenderIcon = (
    previewCanvas: React.RefObject<HTMLCanvasElement>,
    selectedColor: Color,
    selectedSVG: Svg
): void => {
    const [fetchedSvg, setFetchedSvg] = useState<string>("");

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(selectedSVG.uri)
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(data => {
                const domParser = new DOMParser();
                const parsedSvg = domParser.parseFromString(data, "image/svg+xml");

                if (selectedColor.type === "Light") {
                    parsedSvg.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0].setAttribute("fill", "white");
                } else {
                    parsedSvg.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0].setAttribute("fill", "black");
                }

                return parsedSvg.toString();
            })
            .then(data => setFetchedSvg(data));
    }, [selectedColor, selectedSVG]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (previewCanvas.current) {
            const ctx = previewCanvas.current.getContext("2d");

            if (ctx) {
                // draw icon background color
                ctx.fillStyle = selectedColor.color;
                ctx.fillRect(0, 0, previewCanvas.current.width, previewCanvas.current.height);

                // draw icon svg
                const offset = previewCanvas.current.width - PREVIEW_SVG_SIZE;
                const svgIconImage = new Image();

                svgIconImage.setAttribute("src", `data:image/svg+xml,${fetchedSvg}`);
                svgIconImage.setAttribute("width", `${PREVIEW_SVG_SIZE}`);

                svgIconImage.onload = () => {
                    ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
                    ctx.drawImage(
                        svgIconImage,
                        offset / window.devicePixelRatio,
                        offset / window.devicePixelRatio,
                        PREVIEW_SVG_SIZE,
                        PREVIEW_SVG_SIZE
                    );
                };
            }
        }
    }, [previewCanvas, selectedColor, selectedSVG, fetchedSvg]);
};
```